# no result on select query using Npgsql and c#

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npgsql

I tried to search a lot for tutorials on Npgsql and c#. but I couldn't resolve the below problem.

When I run the program, my programs stop and breaks at execute query. and when I try debug and check the return value from the execute reader is empty.

below is the sample code:

```
string user=textBox1.Text;
NpgsqlConnection dataconnect = new NpgsqlConnection(
  "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=dbuser;Password=dbpass;Database=dbname;");


string query = "Select USERNAME from helperdata.credentials where USERNAME = "
    + textBox1.Text + " and PASSWORD = " + textBox2.Text;
dataconnect.Open();

NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, dataconnect);


NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

if(reader.Read())
{
    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Login failed");
}
reader.Close();
dataconnect.Close();
```

When I try to run the below query in Pgsql it returns the data.

```
       Select "USERNAME" from helperdata.credentials where "USERNAME" = 'admin'
```

I am new to Npgsql.

I would also like if someone could provide me some good tutorial sites which provides detail explanation of Npgsql and C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are expecting only a single result you can use "Getting a single result value using the NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() method" as per the user manual.  http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html

Comment: Also check your new NpgsqlConnection(
  "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=dbuser;Password=dbpass;Database=dbname;"); connection string if the db user name / password and db name is correct.

Comment: @ray thanks for the link. I tried using executescalar() but no luck.

Comment: I already tested the NpgsqlConnection and it is correct.

Comment: ok I believe there is something wrong with my query as I figured this error        "Additional information: ERROR: 42703: column "username" does not exist"

Comment: @ray I figured out what was the problem. My USERNAME column should have been in double qoutes. Its working great now. Thanks again for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have identified two problems in your code. The first the usage of uppercase letters on [PostgreSQL identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). PostgreSQL allows identifiers with other than simple lowercase letter, but only if you quote them.

In fact, you can use, for instance:

```
CREATE TABLE helperdata.credentials (... USERNAME varchar, ...);
```

But PostgreSQL will convert it to:

```
CREATE TABLE helperdata.credentials (... username varchar, ...);
```

So, to make it really left with uppercase, you have to quote it as following:

```
CREATE TABLE helperdata.credentials (... "USERNAME" varchar, ...);
```

And that seems to be the way you have created your table, and the problem with that is that always you refers to that table in a query, you'll have to quote it. So the beginning of your query should be:

```
string query = "Select \"USERNAME\" from helperdata.credentials ... ";
```

My recommendation, is to modify your column and table names to don't use such identifiers. For this case you can do:

```
ALTER TABLE helperdata.credentials RENAME COLUMN "USERNAME" TO username;
```

The second problem, is the lack of string quotation when you concatenated the username from the textbox into the query. So, you should do something as the following (**BAD PRACTICE**):

```
string query = "Select \"USERNAME\" from helperdata.credentials where \"USERNAME\" = '"
    + textBox1.Text + "' and \"PASSWORD\" = '" + textBox2.Text + "'";
```

There is a huge problem with that, you can have SQL injection. You could create a function (or use one from Npgsql, not sure if there is) to escape the string, or, more appropriately, you should use a function that accept parameters in the query using `NpgsqlCommand`, which you can simple send the parameters or a use a prepared statement.

[Check the Npgsql documentation](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html), and find for "Using parameters in a query" and "Using prepared statements" to see examples (there are no anchors in the HTML to link here, so you'll have to search).